# Can we have more than 1 Sendlog DE for one of the triggered send email only?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, triggered-send, send-email

We have a SendLog DE to which the data gets logged for all of the emails (triggered + user initiated). But I wish to create another sendlog DE  only for one of the triggered send.
Is it possible to have 2 sendlogs for one of the triggered send?

Also how can I take the  the ampscript data from email into the Sendlog at the time of the send?

Answer (score 1):

> There is a limit of only one Data Extension to be created using the SendLog DE

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333925&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1&language=en_US

But for triggered send, you can have a Triggered Send Data Extension, there is no limit on the number of those.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_create_triggered_send_data_extension.htm&language=th&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&language=th

For logging ampscript variables in the SendLog, just add a field to the send log with the exact name of the variable (but without the `@` sign and it will log those variables automatically, eg. if you want to log a variable called `@couponCode`, add `couponCode` to the SendLog.

Comment: + For AMPScript personalisation stings, omit the leading underscore. "_EmailName" -> "EmailName" in your SendLog DE. You can have multiple SendLogs - one for each Business Unit. You can't have multiple SendLogs in the same BU. "Enterprise Send Logging" (Support Request) allows only one SendLog in the entire account - all BUs log to the same table (very useful).

Comment: @user99586 - if this answer helped you, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark - thanks!